# How to fix VFX to showing up Unity 3D

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine

I'm using [Stylized Slash VFX](https://assetstore.unity.com/packages/vfx/particles/stylized-slash-vfx-200233#description) asset for my game currently. When I call the `.Play()` function from script on play it shows up in the editor tab. But, in the game and build it doesn't. Does anyone know why and how to fix this?

Comment: What error does the console give you when outputting?

Comment: It could be that they’re written for a different renderer or platform and not compatible with the platform or render pipeline you’re using. The package’s Asset Store page says it’s compatible with URP only. (Expand the “Render pipeline compatibility” section near the top of the page.)

Comment: Is it caused by calling play in update()?